# CSS @font-face eot ( HelveticaNeueLT Std Thin ) Not working for IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have wrote a css for add "HelveticaNeueLT Std Thin" font for my website. But that css doesn't work for IE browers, also that font can't convert to eot via http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

That website gives error **"Adobe has requested that their font HelveticaNeueLT Std Thin Regular be blacklisted by the Generator. You will not be able to convert this font."**

So I convert this form another website but didn't work,

This is my css, this work for other browers, But IE has problem.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Helvetica_Thin;
    src: url("fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Th_0.otf") format("opentype");
    src: url("fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Th_new.eot"),
         url("fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Th.ttf") format('truetype'),
         url("fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Th_new.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype');
}
```

this is link for download above font http://font2s.com/fonts/50728/helvetica_neue_lt_std_35_thin.html#.VBvpBxYsD3Y

Comment: what is your IE version?

Comment: @Cattla I have checked all ie version ie 7, 8 , 9, 10 doesn't work

Comment: Did you manage to generate the `.eot` font?  That's the one ie uses so if it did not generate properly then it won't work ps you need to pay for a license to use that font on your website

Comment: @Pete could you please give me good website or software link for convert to eot

Comment: @Pete or similar font

Comment: https://typekit.com/lists/alternatives-to-helvetica

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this format

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyWebFont';
src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
   url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
   url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
   url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```